# Copy string to clipboard, without using a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I have this code that works:

```
let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
textarea.textContent = 'the string you want to copy';
document.body.appendChild(textarea);
textarea.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

as you can see - I have the string to copy in hand. But I have to create a temporary hidden DOM element to score the string before copying to the clipboard.

My question is, is there some API to copy to clipboard without needing the DOM at all? something like this:

```
document.execCommand('copy', 'the string data to put in clipboard');
```

seems weird that the DOM is necessary to do this. Also, as a side note, this clipboard API is super strange, anyone else agree?

Comment: Some things in browser require a user event to prevent malicious or abusive unwanted actions

Comment: yeah but in this case, there is no click or anything, there is no user event that I can think of?

Comment: You normally need a user event to initialize it writing to the clipboard. And for the longest time you could not do it. Wrap it in a simple helper function and it will be easy to call.

Comment: This happens to be for a google-chrome-extension, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I know what you mean, regarding security. But my code above works - I assume it can run without any real user event. I just want to know if I can copy something to the clipboard without using a DOM element

Comment: No, there's no such API.

Comment: no such API to copy a JS string to the clipboard?

Comment: ANd you are out of luck really with the extension api because of https://developer.chrome.com/apps/clipboard being dev branch

Comment: well, the clipboard only needs to work in the extension code, not the page, so it will work for my use case. the code snippet works in a chrome extension if it's running in the chrome extension process.

Comment: The only alternative to DOM is to write an external utility, separately installed, which can communicate via nativeMessaging API with the extension and use OS to copy to the clipboard, but obviously this "solution" is even worse.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I can live with the solution I have now, just curious if there are alternatives - for example, the chrome extension API, with background script, content script, popup script, etc, I kinda want to know where the clipboard is available and where it's not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the asynchronous **Clipboard API** which is used to implement cut, copy, and paste features within a web application but keep in mind that it works with secured connection(HTTPS) and localhost.

```
const copyToClipboard = (textToCopy) => {
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy)
   .then(() => {
      // actions to take
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong', err);
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same question like you but none of solution provided the solution without affecting DOM. Following built-in function help you.

```
copyToClipboard("Your variable/string")
```

**copyToClipboard** function allows you to copy the variable or strings to the system clipboard. This is a part of [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) click for Docs.