# Copying a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to put a variable in the clipboard?  I've seen a lot of posts that do this by selecting the text existing in a DOM element and then copying it which is fairly straightforward but I haven't seen one that copies something that isn't in the DOM.
I'd like to take a variable or a constant holding a string and send it to the clipboard without it ever appearing in the browser window (even as a hidden element). 
I know using a hidden element would be a fast solution to this but it feels a little hacky if there is a more concise way.

Comment: As far as I know you cant do it and I searched for quite some time. Everything I have seen involves creating a text area out of view seleting the text copying then destroying the element.

Comment: see the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215841/copy-string-to-clipboard-without-using-a-dom-element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write). it doesn't have full support yet but it's [pretty good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText#Browser_compatibility).

you can use it like so:

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText("hello from site!")
  .then(() => console.log(`wrote to clipboard!`))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

**Notice that this works only if the current website is focused (the document is focused)**

In order to **read** from the clipboard, you can use the following function:

```js
navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

This one requires **two things** in order to work:

- same as before, the user needs to be focused on the website
- user will be prompted to confirm the site's ability to read from the clipboard (since it can contain sensitive data):

  [image]

#### Firefox

For Firefox, in addition to asking the user for permission to read the clipboard, [it also only allows pasting it into a textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Browser-specific_considerations_2):

> Firefox supports the "clipboardRead" permission from version 54, but only supports pasting into elements in content editable mode, which for content scripts only works with a . For background scripts, any element can be set to content editable mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm developing this for a lot of corporate users on IE but I will check this as correct because technically this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for Javascript rather than jquery, so here you go.

```
function toClip(text) {
    var copy = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(copy);
    copy.value = text;
    copy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(copy);
}
```

While this doesn't use an existing element in the DOM, it creates one and immediately removes it.

This